# Passing a string from C++ to Java using JNI crashing (Android)

Tags: java, android, c++, crash, java-native-interface

I'm encountering issues when trying to pass a string from C++ to Java.  Here's the code on the C++ side:

```
void AndroidJNIInterfacer::callJavaVoidMethod(const char* name, const char* sig, const char* char1)
{
    jmethodID method = getJavaMethod(name, sig);
    jstring argString = env->NewStringUTF(char1);

    if (method != NULL)
        env->CallVoidMethod(nativeActivity, method, argString);

    jvm->GetEnv((void**) &env, version);
}
```

And here's the code on the Java side:

```
public void showLeaderboardActivity(final String id)
    {
        //int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 100;
        Log.d("MyNativeActivity", "Before id");
        Log.d("MyNativeActivity", id);
        //startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getLeaderboardIntent(id), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
    }
```

And here's the logcat output:

```
12-16 01:57:58.697: D/MyNativeActivity(22071): Before id
12-16 01:57:58.721: I/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
12-16 01:57:59.721: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:00.471: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #2 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050db20 self=0x117d60
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22074 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1b0 self=0xce60
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:00.475: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:137)
12-16 01:58:00.479: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.madstermadster.myNativeActivity.MyNativeActivity$1.run(MyNativeActivity.java:46)
12-16 01:58:00.483: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 01:58:00.483: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:58:00.483: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 01:58:00.490: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-16 01:58:00.490: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:00.494: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-16 01:58:00.494: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-16 01:58:00.494: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 01:58:00.494: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:01.244: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #3 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:01.244: I/dalvikvm(22071): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:01.248: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050db20 self=0x117d60
12-16 01:58:01.248: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22074 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
12-16 01:58:01.248: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:01.248: I/dalvikvm(22071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:01.248: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1b0 self=0xce60
12-16 01:58:01.256: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
12-16 01:58:01.459: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:01.459: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:137)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.madstermadster.myNativeActivity.MyNativeActivity$1.run(MyNativeActivity.java:46)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 01:58:01.561: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:02.311: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #4 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050db20 self=0x117d60
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22074 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1b0 self=0xce60
12-16 01:58:02.311: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
12-16 01:58:02.686: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:02.725: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:137)
12-16 01:58:02.775: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.madstermadster.myNativeActivity.MyNativeActivity$1.run(MyNativeActivity.java:46)
12-16 01:58:02.803: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 01:58:02.822: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:58:02.854: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 01:58:02.889: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-16 01:58:02.889: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:02.900: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-16 01:58:02.900: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-16 01:58:02.900: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 01:58:02.900: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:03.650: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #5 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050db20 self=0x117d60
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22074 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1b0 self=0xce60
12-16 01:58:03.650: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:137)
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.madstermadster.myNativeActivity.MyNativeActivity$1.run(MyNativeActivity.java:46)
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 01:58:03.654: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-16 01:58:03.658: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:03.658: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-16 01:58:03.658: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-16 01:58:03.658: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 01:58:03.658: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:04.408: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #6 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050db20 self=0x117d60
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22074 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1b0 self=0xce60
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:137)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.madstermadster.myNativeActivity.MyNativeActivity$1.run(MyNativeActivity.java:46)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 01:58:04.408: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:05.158: W/dalvikvm(22071): threadid=4: spin on suspend #7 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050db20 self=0x117d60
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22074 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=582800
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1b0 self=0xce60
12-16 01:58:05.264: I/dalvikvm(22071):   | sysTid=22071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
12-16 01:58:05.268: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:05.350: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:137)
12-16 01:58:05.358: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.madstermadster.myNativeActivity.MyNativeActivity$1.run(MyNativeActivity.java:46)
12-16 01:58:05.358: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-16 01:58:05.358: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-16 01:58:05.361: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-16 01:58:05.365: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-16 01:58:05.365: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 01:58:05.373: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-16 01:58:05.373: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-16 01:58:05.373: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-16 01:58:05.373: I/dalvikvm(22071):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My initial LOGI seems to work, so clearly the java method is correctly being found.  When I reference the id I passed it, though, it crashes, so I suspect the problem is with how I am converting and/or passing the string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm happy to post any other code/answer any questions, of course.  Thanks!

Edit:  The env variable is set by a function setEnv(), which is called prior to any other calls:

```
void setEnv()
{
    jvm->GetEnv((void**) &env, version);
}
```

jvm is set at the very beginning of the program.  I'm confident that both this and getJavaMethod work correctly, as I can make calls into Java to methods without arguments.

Edit 2: Based on some advice from Tom (see below), I now have the following:

```
void AndroidJNIInterfacer::callJavaVoidMethod(const char* name, const char* sig, const char* char1)
{
    jmethodID method = getJavaMethod(name, sig);
    jstring argString = env->NewStringUTF(char1);

    const jchar* result = env->GetStringChars(argString, JNI_FALSE);

    if (method != NULL)
        env->CallVoidMethod(nativeActivity, method, result);

    env->DeleteLocalRef(argString);
}
```

and:

```
public void showLeaderboardActivity(byte[] id)
    {
        //int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 100;
        String sId = String(id);

        Log.d("MyNativeActivity", "Before id");
        Log.d("MyNativeActivity", sId);
        Log.d("MyNativeActivity", "After id");
        //startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getLeaderboardIntent(id), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
    }
```

Which at least no longer completely crashes, but only outputs "Before Id".  I'm pretty sure I'm not actually getting a jbytearray, but I am not sure how to go about getting one exactly.

Edit: Solved!  As it turns out, it is perfectly fine to pass a const char* from C++ to Java, as I was doing initially.  The problem was a silly error I made, which resulted in the wrong version of an overloaded function being called. No value was being set for my id parameter, causing the crash.  So if you have a similar error, it's possible your calling CallVoidMethod (or a similar function) with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: No, this cannot explain your crash, but you should call `DeleteLocalRef()` after the call to Java.

Comment: How do you get the `env` variable in `callJavaVoidMethod` ?

Comment: Thanks, Alex, I updated both the code in my project and in the question.
mbrenon, I edited my question to answer your question.  I don't think it's a problem with getting env, though, because it does appear to call the method, it just crashes when I try to access the parameter.  Unless I misunderstand how something much more fundamental works?

Comment: You can't pass a non-modified UTF-8 string through `NewStringUTF`. Android generally uses standard UTF-8 and the JVM knows that. Call `lang.java.String(byte[])` instead, after copying your string to a `jbytearray`. See [Android JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Tom.  Can I ask for a bit of clarification though?  I've edited my main post again...